# WPF: ComboBox with selecteditem set make not use of SelectedIndex=0?

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem, selectedindex

Why is the first element in my combobox popup menu not shown in the selected item area of

my combobox , when I use the SelectedItem binding? Without that it is showing up ?? Using

the same code selecteditem + selectedindex that is no problem!

```
<ComboBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolclassSubjectViewModels}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSchoolclassSubjectViewModel}"   
        SelectedIndex="0"
        Height="23"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="375,13,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="151">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SchoolclassName}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubjectName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Well as workaround I used:

```
SchoolclassSubjectViewModels.Add(schoolclassSubjectVM);
        SelectedSchoolclassSubjectViewModel = schoolclassSubjectVM;
```

and this:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSchoolclassSubjectViewModel,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

but I would prefer the xaml only way as it should really work.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the reference inside your `ItemsSource` collection is not the same as the one in your `SelectedItem` property. I would venture to guess that you are using one object context to query your database for the list of `SchoolclassSubject` objects which the `ItemsSource` is bound to, but another context to query the actual data item to which you bind the `SelectedItem`. Even though the list contains a reference which represents the value held by your object, it is not really the same reference, but a separate instance of the same data.

There are ways to solve this issue, most of them involve using the `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue` instead of the `SelectedItem` properties, but the concrete solution would be different depending on your particular ORM.

Comment: I use sqlite database with sql pure no ORM.

The first paragraph sounds confusing XD.

What you said can not be true maybe..., because I just found in my code this:

<ComboBox
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSchoolclass}"
 SelectedIndex="0"
 DisplayMemberPath="SchoolclassName"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Schoolclasses}"
 />


The binding in the viewmodel is the same pattern as in the above code. The difference is the ComboBox itemtemplate I did not define specially.