# SelectedIndex Not Showing Default Value in ComboBox when used with SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, mvvm

New/learning WPF with MVVM. I'm trying to get a `ComboBox` to display a default value when linking with a `Label`:

```
<StackPanel ...>
    <ComboBox Name="cboMonth"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MonthsList, Mode=OneWay}"
        DisplayMemberPath="month"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding DisplayCurrentIntMonth,  Mode=Default}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonth, Mode=Default}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding SelectedMonth.month}" />
</StackPanel>
```

`MonthList` is of type `Month` (populated with 01-January, 02-February, ...etc); `Month` has single property, `string month`.

`DisplayCurrentIntMonth` returns an `int`:

```
public int DisplayCurrentIntMonth
{    
    get
    {                
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        return selectedIntMonth = today.Month - 1;
    }
    set
    {                
        if (selectedIntMonth != value)
        {           
            RaisePropertyChanged("DisplayCurrentIntMonth");
        }
    }
}
```

`SelectedMonth` returns a `Month`:

```
public Month SelectedMonth
{
    get
    {                
        return selectedMonth;
    }
    set
    {                
        if (selectedMonth != value)
        {
            selectedMonth = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedMonth");
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will NOT display a default value (in the `ComboBox`) with

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding DisplayCurrentIntMonth, Mode=Default}"
```

but will display a default value (and function completely as desired) with no binding:

```
SelectedIndex="5"
```

I've looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961113/wpf-combobox-with-selecteditem-set-make-not-use-of-selectedindex-0) (among many others) but no luck. Have spent several hours Googling...

Why is the `ComboBox` default value (should be 06-June) not populating when the app first renders?

With help from [Pedro](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1d6ea917-e197-4ac9-b3a1-04301768d8b8/linkbind-label-to-combobox?forum=wpf), got the ComboBox to sync with a Label and ComboBox shows desired item:

```
<StackPanel ...>
    <ComboBox Name="cboMonth"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MonthsList, Mode=TwoWay}"
        DisplayMemberPath="month"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding DisplayCurrentIntMonth,  Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonth, Mode=Default}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding SelectedItem.month, ElementName=cboMonth}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Don't set SelectedItem and SelectedIndex at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my updated code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31124331/wpf-mvvm-selectedindex-binding-property-not-updating-when-combobox-selection-ch) reflects this.